# Loading jQuery with RequireJS: different name convention in third-party libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have an application using some third-party libraries as I also have some plug-ins created by myself using jQuery.

The point is: some third-party libraries are using `$` and other ones `jQuery` as naming convention. The way I'm requiring jQuery through RequireJS is just as that:

```
[...]

var $ = require('jquery');

[...]
```

This way, I get the following console message as return:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.scrolly.js:79
>
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Then, I figured out a candidate solution by creating two variables and requiring jQuery in both:

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    jQuery = require('jquery');
```

So, as you can see this "solution" is redundant, unnecessary and unsophisticated — I need something consistent, something better.

Someone can share an idea with me?

Comment: likely you have to shim in scrolly.

Comment: What do you mean with "have to shim"? Sorry, I already heard about it, but didn't get further.

Comment: Quickest (not the most elegant) thing really is var $ = jQuery = require('jquery') so you're only actually doing the require once and jQuery is just a pointer to $, so it's still performant.

Comment: its a requirejs concept. have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white), I could use an elegant-way solution called as [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Let's do this step-by-step. My HTML is calling for `app.js` as `require.js` wants:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my ***old*** `js/app.js`:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        modernizr: 'vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min',
        scrolly: 'vendor/jquery.scrolly'
    }
});

require(['main']);
```

Now, here the magic happens — see yourself my new `js/app.js`:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        modernizr: 'vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min',
        scrolly: 'vendor/jquery.scrolly'
    },
    shim: {
        'scrolly': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'scrolly'
        }
    }
});

require(['main']);
```

#### What's the big deal?

The greatness here is the simplicity as RequireJS thinks. As far I could understand, **shim config** is something like a "dependency manager" for libraries. For example, `scrolly` is a third-party library dependant of jQuery that have been already loaded — why then should we load it again? There's no need! We just need to inject its usefulness onto `scrolly` mechanisms that uses jQuery resources.

Another popular example is [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/). Its single hard dependency is [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org). To teach Backbone that Underscore is available for use, we supply its dependency through shim config as that:

```
[...]

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: '_'
        }
    }

[...]
```

So, that's it.